# Using terminal on Jupyter Lab not working

Tags: python, powershell, terminal, spacy, jupyter-lab

I am working on Jupyter Lab, and I opened the terminal. I tried to install the module `spacy`, but when I came to the part where it said `$ python ...`, it said `/bin/bash: python: command not found`.

My  code:

```
$ pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
$ pip install -U spacy
$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

The output:

---

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/repl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (67.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.38.4)
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: spacy in /home/repl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (3.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: typer<0.8.0,>=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<1.11.0,>=1.7.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (1.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.2.0,>=0.9.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (1.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: langcodes<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.11 in /home/repl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<3.0.0,>=2.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (2.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pathy>=0.10.0 in /home/repl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: smart-open<7.0.0,>=5.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (5.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<2.1.0,>=2.0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (2.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (4.64.0)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<8.2.0,>=8.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (8.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/repl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spacy) (67.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy-loggers<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from spacy) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from packaging>=20.0->spacy) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from pydantic!=1.8,!=1.8.1,<1.11.0,>=1.7.4->spacy) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: confection<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from thinc<8.2.0,>=8.1.0->spacy) (0.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.8.0,>=0.7.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from thinc<8.2.0,>=8.1.0->spacy) (0.7.9)
Requirement already satisfied: click<9.0.0,>=7.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from typer<0.8.0,>=0.3.0->spacy) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from jinja2->spacy) (2.1.1)
/bin/bash: python: command not found
```

---

And the whole point of this was to load the `spacy` `'en_core_web_sm'` tool.

If this is unfixable, then what other ways are there to load the `en_core_web_sm` model?

Comment: Try adding sudo to command so it operates as an Admin : sudo python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

Comment: @jdweng it replies with, `bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: You are not logging as a Admin (Super User).  You need to use a SU account to install apps.

Comment: Ok, i'll try do that.

Comment: it might be unrelated to jupyter but only to your environment/operating system/installation. Have you tried `python3` instead?

Comment: @krassowski Thanks for solving the question - `python3` worked! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?